# Error Deserializing Xml to Object - same entity name

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

**XML I am attempting to deserialize**

```
<x>
    <result result="1" />
    <result redirect="http://blahblahblah.com/?data=a" />
    <result memo1="foo" />
    <result memo2="bar" />
             .
             .
             .
</x>
```

**Class I am trying to deserialize to:**

```
[XmlRoot("x"), XmlType("x")]
public class EmptyModel
{
    [XmlArray("x")]
    [XmlArrayItem("result")]
    public List<ResultModel> result { get; set; }
}

[XmlType("result")]
public class ResultModel
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string redirect { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string err_code { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string err_detail { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string memo1 { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string memo2 { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string result { get; set; }
}
```

But I can't correct make the model binding.

```
var a = xml.ToXmlDeserialize<EmptyModel>();
```

How do I make the right model?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
[XmlRoot("x")]
public class EmptyModel
{
    [XmlElement()]
    public List<ResultModel> result { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: 'XmlElement' attribute type is not available in this Declaration. 'property, indexer, field, param, return' declaration can only be used.